# How to balance unique values in an array Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, random, indexing

I have a vector

```
Y = [1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

1 occurs 17 times

0 occurs 21 times

How can I randomly remove 0s so that both values have equal amounts, such as 1 (17 times) and 0 (17 times)?

This should also work on much bigger matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with your example

```
Y = [1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

You can do the following:

```
% Get the indices of the value which is more common (`0` here)
zeroIdx = find(~Y); % equivalent to find(Y==0)
% Get random indices to remove
remIdx = randperm(nnz(~Y), nnz(~Y) - nnz(Y));
% Remove elements
Y(zeroIdx(remIdx)) = [];
```

You could combine the last two lines, but I think it would be less clear.

The `randperm` line is choosing the correct number of elements to remove from random indices between 1 and the number of zeros.

Answer (score 3):

#### If the data can only have two values

Values are assumed to be `0` and `1`. The most common value is randomly removed to equalize their counts:

```
Y = [1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]; % data
ind0 = find(Y==0); % indices of zeros
ind1 = find(Y==1); % indices of ones
t(1,1:numel(ind0)) = ind0(randperm(numel(ind0))); % random permutation of indices of zeros
t(2,1:numel(ind1)) = ind1(randperm(numel(ind1))); % same for ones. Pads shorter row with 0
t = t(:, all(t,1)); % keep only columns that don't have padding
result = Y(sort(t(:))); % linearize, sort and use those indices into the data
```

#### Generalization for more than two values

Values are arbitrary. All values except the least common one are randomly removed to equalize their counts:

```
Y = [0 1 2 0 2 1 1 2 0 2 1 2 2 0 0]; % data
vals = [0 1 2]; % or use vals = unique(Y), but absent values will not be detected
t = [];
for k = 1:numel(vals) % loop over values
    ind_k = find(Y==vals(k));
    t(k, 1:numel(ind_k)) = ind_k(randperm(numel(ind_k)));
end
t = t(:, all(t,1));
result = Y(sort(t(:)));
```